# Is there a fix for my code not declaring an int to what I select it to be in a if else loop?

Tags: c++

When I run and test the code, I select 2 for the second option, but when I do, it reverts it to 1 and selects the first option in my if-then loop.

I've tried moving the declaration to right below the console input, and I've tried using other numbers besides 2.I moved the console output so I know what it selects, and that didn't help with anything.

Here's my entire code for this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <conio.h>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    std::cout << "HELLOW THERE!\n";
    char enter[2];
    int help2 = 0;
    char help[20];
    std::cin >> help;
    std::cout << "hello, " << help <<" this was a test, thanks\n";
    std::cout << "lol jk no it wasnt\n";
    std::cout << "come on, " << help << "\n";
    char name[20] = "Crilbus";
    std::cout << "press any key + enter to continue...\n";
    std::cin >> enter;
    std::cout <<"Your name is " << name << " now haha gotem\n";
    std::cout << "so, " << name << ", you were walking to " << help <<" and you bought a cherry.\n";
    std::cout << "JUST ONE CHERRY, FORGET ABOUT THE OTHER 4.\n";
    std::cout <<"so what do you do?\n";
    std::cout <<"do you eat it or throw it at someone?\n";
    std::cout <<"press 1 to eat it and 2 to throw it.\n";
    int henlep;
    std::cin >> henlep;

    if (int henlep = 1) {
        std::cout <<"you chose " << henlep << ",\n";
        std::cout <<"you fool!\n";
        std::cout << "honestly if you ate it you ruined the fun. compile this again and press 2\n";
    }
    else if (int henlep = 2){
        std::cout <<"ok so you through it at my boy gavin and he decided to 1v1 you.\n";
        std::cout << "do you press 1 to fight, or press 2 to run away?\n";
        std::cin >> henlep;
    }
}
```

I expect the console output to be 2 when I select 2 in the console input, but I get the console output as 1

Comment: Also: I highly recommend you use proper identation, it will help you and everyone who reads your code (like me) to keep track of control flow.

Comment: Furthermore, don't include headers you don't use as it seems to be the case with `conio.h`.

Comment: Another thing: There are pros and cons to using `using namespace std;` but what it does is it will let you use symbols in the `std` namespace (like `cout` and `cin`) without specifyng the namespace. So in this code, you can either leave out the `using namespace std;` or all the `std::` prefixes.

Comment: @Gamification: I think that last one isn't quite right. `std::endl` flushes buffers, which makes the app run slower, so there's a major performance difference between the two. And since `<<` is a formatted output, `'\n'` will result in the local newline character regardless.

Comment: @MooingDuck oh my, thanks for pointing that out. So I was always under a wrong impression. I'll delete the comment so no one picks it up. I wrongly stated that std::endl was for platform compatibiliy but usually equal to '\n' – So I was wrong in both regards.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That is because `int henlep = 1` declares henlep as int assigns 1 to it. However, what you seem to want is to compare it with one. For that you have to use the comparison operator `==` like so:

```
if (henlep == 1) {
    std::cout <<"you chose " << henlep << ",\n";
    std::cout <<"you fool!\n";
    std::cout << "honestly if you ate it you ruined the fun. compile this again and press 2\n";
}
```

Comment: Thank you bud this really helped my program. Thank you and Have a nice day.

Comment: If that solved your problem and answered your question, please *accept* it by pressing the green ✓to the left of the post. Thanks